# Limit count modifier to iterate commands

Tags: vim, vi

Vim provides [the count modifier](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#[count]), which is used to multiply or add iterations to a command. If you use vim, you are probably familiar with it: It allows you to write `50j` to move down 50 times.

Occasionally I manage to enter a big number without noticing, while I am actually using other applications. When I then proceed to use vim and for example type `o` to begin a new line, vim naturally tries to create a huge amount of new lines, which slowly fills up the memory and then gets killed by the kernel OOM killer.

Is there any way to limit the counter or to add a confirmation if it is greater than some threshold?

Comment: Not really a limit, but you can use `:set showcmd` to show the pending command, including the pending count, on the last line of Vim. That might help you spot that there's a huge count if you manage to spot that in the last line before typing the normal mode command that would get affected by it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already had that activated for several years now. On rare occasion it still happens to me though, so I thought maybe it can be disabled. Worst case i will patch it myself.

Comment: I don't think there's a solution out-of-the-box. I'm thinking you *might* be able to implement something like this by mapping all the numbers from 0 to 9 in normal mode and checking whether `v:count` is already set and handling that. I'll try to play with that, if I get to anything useful I'll post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *almost* works:

```
function! UpdateCount(n) abort
    let limit = get(g:, 'counter_limit', 99)
    if v:count == 0
        return ''.a:n
    elseif v:count == limit
        return ''
    elseif 10 * v:count + a:n > limit
        return repeat("\<Del>", strlen(v:count)).limit
    else
        return ''.a:n
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> 0 UpdateCount(0)
nnoremap <expr> 1 UpdateCount(1)
nnoremap <expr> 2 UpdateCount(2)
nnoremap <expr> 3 UpdateCount(3)
nnoremap <expr> 4 UpdateCount(4)
nnoremap <expr> 5 UpdateCount(5)
nnoremap <expr> 6 UpdateCount(6)
nnoremap <expr> 7 UpdateCount(7)
nnoremap <expr> 8 UpdateCount(8)
nnoremap <expr> 9 UpdateCount(9)
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't work for the `0` key, since Vim [disables any mappings for `0` while entering a count](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/normal.c#L645), which makes sense since `0` by itself is the command to go to the first character of the line and if these mappings weren't disabled then a command such as `nnoremap 0 ^` would break usage of `0` in counts...

So, yeah, other than patching Vim to add a limit, I don't really see a good way to fix this *in general*.

If this is a problem with some commands more than others (i.e. insertion commands, such as `o` or `i` or `A`, etc.) then you might want to consider adding a mapping to those, inspecting `v:count` in those and preventing them if the count is above a certain limit.

For example:

```
function! LimitCount(cmd) abort
    let limit = get(g:, 'counter_limit', 99)
    if v:count > limit
        echomsg "Count ".v:count." is too large, aborting execution of '".a:cmd."' command."
        " Use Ctrl-C to erase the pending count and avoid applying it to the next command.
        return "\<C-C>"
    else
        return a:cmd
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> o LimitCount('o')
nnoremap <expr> i LimitCount('i')
" And so on for other insertion commands...
```

Comment: Great suggestions! I think the first version is already good enough for my purpose. If I still have problems and get bored I might implement a limiter or threshold in vim directly.